# Error exporting android .apk from Eclipse when using Proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, proguard

I want to export my android application from Eclipse to a release .apk. So I right click the project name in eclipse, select export, go through all the exporting dialogs, and finally I get these errors:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a command file.
'-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a command file.
```

I am running Windows Vista, and I have Eclipse and Android SDK correctly configured. I'm pretty sure something is missing in the PATH variable, but since the filename is truncated because of Window's space character and Eclipse being confused, I don't know what to do.

Has anyone has already encountered this problem ?

If i disable Proguard, I don't get the error any more. But I need Proguard...

Comment: It seems to me obvious either the path is wrong or you are trying to export a file other than the apk

Comment: usually when you see 'C:\Program' it means that wherever the path is specified should have double quotes because of the space in the path between Program and Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if anyone has the same problem: It was under Windows>Preferences>Android>Sdk location.
I used the path "c:\Progra~1\Android\android-sdk-windows".